# How do I get the proper syntax for media path in image link url

Tags: magento-2.1, php

What is the proper syntax for adding the media path to the base/full/ and base/thumbnails/ link urls?

```
echo "<a href=\"base/full/".$curimg."\"><img src=\"base/thumbnails/".$curimg."\"></a>";
```

Full code for reference:

```
<div id="swatchesArea" class="ui-corner-all">
    <?php
    $images = scandir('/home/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/public_html/app/code/Martens/Showroom/view/frontend/web/images/base/thumbnails/');
        $ignore = Array('.', '..');
        foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo "<a href=\"base/full/".$curimg."\"><img src=\"base/thumbnails/".$curimg."\"></a>";
        }
      };
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get media path in two ways see below:

1-Way:-

use

```
Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
protected $_filesystem;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $_filesystem,
)
{
    $this->_filesystem = $_filesystem;
}
```

Now you can get media path by,

```
$mediapath=$this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
```

2-Way:-

If you want to use object manager, then you can use this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$fileSystem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
$mediaPath=$fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
echo $mediaPath;
```

Comment: Can you also tell me the answer to my question how to get a valid code by implementing the media path into the "href" and "img src" urls?

Comment: After getting a $mediapath OR $media  value you can use path with folder name and then filename.

Please see the example: <a href="<?php echo $media;?>/foldername/filename.jpg">anchor tag<a/>

Comment: I try not to use objectmanager directly so I will go with your 1st option . The 1st piece of code goes in to the block file? And 2nd piece of code goes into the file where the href and img urls are?

Comment: Is it possible to use getViewFileUrl('$curimg') ?